# pygame.FULLSCREEN makes the display disappear

Tags: python, pygame, fullscreen

I was trying to do my project in full screen and i used full screen but sometimes the display comes for 1 second then it disappears and i tried it with no full screen and it works but it doesn't in full screen and my code is:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init() screen=pygame.display.set_mode((1360,768),pygame.FULLSCREEN,pygame.RESIZABLE)
pygame.display.init()
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Please read [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're having trouble because you pass `pygame.RESIZABLE` as the third argument (the `depth`) to [`pygame.display.set_mode`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) whereas you should combine it with the `pygame.FULLSCREEN` flag with a bitwise OR.

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1360,768), pygame.FULLSCREEN|pygame.RESIZABLE)
```

Comment: If that doesn't work, there are more problems and you have to post a more complete example.